# What are the necessary plugins in VIM for Latex?

Tags: vim, latex

What are your favourite plugins in VIM for Latex editing? Is there some ready variant of VIM for Latex?

Comment: This is not a very well-formed question, as per the FAQ.  You should aska question that has one best answer (despite that you accepted an answer)

Comment: The FAQ needs an overhaul.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, I think the default support that Vim includes for `filetype=tex` is already quite good. So strictly, no plugins are necessary.

However, I do recommend a few settings that you can cherry-pick from and adapt to your own taste. See the help to see what each command/setting does.

```
setlocal iskeyword+=:,-
setlocal makeprg=pdflatex\ -file-line-error\ -interaction=nonstopmode\ %

inoremap <buffer> { {}<ESC>i
inoremap <buffer> [ []<ESC>i

iab <buffer> ,b \begin{
iab <buffer> ,e \end{
" More abbreviations...
```

You can put these in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` to load them for every `tex` file. The following are some global settings that I keep in `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"
set suffixes+=.log,.aux,.bbl,.blg,.idx,.ilg,.ind,.out,.pdf
```

Answer (score 14):

#1: [VIM LaTeX-suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net)
 from http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 5):

Choose from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=latex&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search), depending on what you intend to do.

Comment: The linklist here is very good, this needs more upvotes. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You probably want LaTex Suite. See [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=475).

**Edit:** I forgot to add the link to their web page which is [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what have been mentioned above, i recommend to give 'live-latex-preview' ([link](https://github.com/ying17zi/vim-live-latex-preview)) a try. It helps to preview the document while editing. Although the live-preview feature is only suitable for short documents, it definitely makes experimenting to be more fun...